# Ionic2 using a Generic Oauth2 provider

Tags: ionic2

I have been trying to find information on how to use a generic oauth2 provider in Ionic2 but could not find anything useful. In most of the cases I can only see info for Facebook or Google but no info on how to use your own provider. Have anyone done this before? Or does anyone know any useful links? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around some you've got a few choices. http://ionic.io/cloud#authentication looks promising though I've never played with it. Here's one which should give you a bit more control, https://github.com/nraboy/ng2-cordova-oauth

Further... there's nothing saying you need to use something specific to ionic2. Why not use any of the plethora of oauth libraries out there and wrap it in your own service to use with ionic's page nav?

Comment: Thank you Joshua, I will give it a try.  Actually I'm just getting started with Ionic and Angular2 and wanted to get some real information before starting to build the project and play with Ionic. I've done some programming in PHP but nothing Ionic related before. Thanks for your help mate.